# SQL Count digits in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have a table of the following information.

```
description: adjkfa34kj34kj33j4k3jk4
description: adfkjjkdf34_3434kjkjkj3
description: akjdfkjadfkjadkjfkjadfj
description: 34394394093040930949039
```

How would I edit the SQL query below to count the number of digits (i.e. [0-9]) in the strings?

```
select description as num_count
from posts;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to get rid of all the other characters:

```
select length(regexp_replace(description, '[^0-9]', '', 'g'))
```

Comment: I believe the code above is missing a closing ")" at the end of the code. When I tried it, I get  the error: "function len(text) does not exist".

Comment: I got it working with: length(regexp_replace(ticker, '[^0-9]', '', 'g'))

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
    (
        @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @intAlpha INT
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

        BEGIN
            WHILE @intAlpha > 0
            BEGIN
                    SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
                    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
            END
        END

        RETURN @strAlphaNumeric
    END
    GO

/*For Example,*/
SELECT LEN(dbo.udf_GetNumeric('') )
SELECT LEN(dbo.udf_GetNumeric('asdf1234a1s2d3f4@@@') )
SELECT LEN(dbo.udf_GetNumeric('123ghdfhdhh456'))
SELECT LEN(dbo.udf_GetNumeric(NULL) )
```

SELECT LEN(dbo.udf_GetNumeric(description)) AS num_count
FROM posts;

Comment: This seems like alot of code. What are your thoughts on length(regexp_replace(ticker, '[^0-9]', '', 'g'))

Comment: this looks like `sql server` syntax, not `postgresql`

Comment: 'regexp_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name. i got this error.while using regexp_replace in sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

In presto I used the following:

```
SELECT CARDINALITY(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('a123', '\d')) -- returns 3
```